# swift: make navigation bar Right-to-left (rtl) with both right and left items like back

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization, right-to-left

I have `UIViewController` with `UINavigationBarDelegate` delegate and I set everything's programmatically and my app is multi language so I need RTL (Right to Left) support in every section like NavigationBar. I used this approach:

```
if MSGlobal.setting.language.direction == .L2R
{
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(rightItems, animated: true)
}
else
{
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems(rightItems, animated: true)
}
let stackCount = navigationController!.viewControllers.count
if stackCount == 1
{
    let leftBtnItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"drawer"), landscapeImagePhone: UIImage(named:"drawer"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cb_drawerTapped:")
    if MSGlobal.setting.language.direction == .L2R
    {
        navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(leftBtnItem, animated: true)
    }
    else
    {
        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(leftBtnItem, animated: true)
    }
}
else
{
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cb_back:")
}
```

Everything's work fine in LTR language like English, But in RTL language back button not shown. My result must be like this:

```
LTR:   [ <      Title      [btn1...btnn]]
RTL:   [[btnn...btn1]      Title      > ]
```

Comment: What is MSGlobal? This should all be automatic; you shouldn't have to do anything. If you're running on iOS 9, with an RTL language set, the left and right bar button items change positions automatically.

Comment: MSGkibal is a class with public static data that shared with whole app, I'm using iOS 8 and it's soon to use 9

Comment: Too soon? iOS 9 has been out for nearly 3 months now...

Comment: Many of popular apps in store support iOS 6 & 7, So it's not a good option for me to ignore iOS 8.

Comment: This does not stop you from using the iOS 9 SDK, and taking advantage of features available in iOS 9, whilst still supporting older OSs. Also, if you look at the usage numbers, I would argue that it's quite pointless to continue supporting both 6 and 7. (Especially 6)

Comment: You are right and I want to support 8 & 9

Comment: Then just use standard API, and it will be flipped automatically on iOS 9.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this ? Kindly help me if yes.

Comment: @Noorul Yes, I found

Comment: can you share me the solution for this.?

Answer (score 8):

If your goal is to have right `UIBarButtonItem` with back action , you can change it through Storyboard by changing `Semantic` to `Force-Right-to-Left`. or by code below:

### Swift 5

inside  your `ViewController` `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

If You want to change navigation bar and the navigation controller flow to right to left direction you can use like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
}
```

But you should mention that it wont change **`Swipe Direction`**, It only effect on navigationBar, If you want to change the **`Swipe Direction`** then you can use:

```
self.navigationController?.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

If you want to do all of them in one line and change the whole app RTL use:

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```